# how to deserialize object (java serialize object) in node js?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I have use Kafka which produces (returns) serialize object 
`List<T>` which i need to de-serialize in node JS ? I have tried JSON.parse() which did not work very well.

Comment: Why did JSON.parse not work well? Are you really sending JSON (or a Java binary serialized object)? If the latter, you should update the sender. Only Java code can really decode the output of ObjectOutputStream, it's a bad fit for anything cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

Java won't serialize java objects to JSON objects thus `JSON.parse()` won't work. You should try out something like `GSON` for serializing java objects to JSON objects and passing them along to your node.js application.

Comment: Actually kafka produce serialize java object which i will consume in node app so can't serialize to JSON through java.